# Bad request when calling rest api using curl or Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, git-bash, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I want to convert speech to text using Microsoft speech-to-text service from within a bash script or PowerShell script. I tried using curl (Git bash) and Invoke-RestMethod (PowerShell) to send my 16 bit pcm mono wav audio file to the stt service.

The service is working, I used a c# example provided by Microsoft to test it. With the c# example I'm able to send the audio file and receive the text from the stt services.

Now I wanted to do this in a script.

Using **curl** in Git Bash:

```
curl -X POST "https://westus.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US&format=detailed" \ 
     -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <my_subscription_key>" \
     -H "Content-Type: audio/wav; codecs=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000" \
     --data-binary audio.wav

Insufficient data to detect audio format: 7 bytes
```

Even using `-d` or `--data` or `--data-raw` instead of `--data-binary` doesn't change anything.

Using **Invoke-RestMethod** in PowerShell:

```
$audioBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("c:\full\path\to\aduio\file.wav")

Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Method Post `
    -Uri "https://westeurope.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US&format=detailed" `
    -Headers @{'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' = '<my_subscription_key>'} `
    -ContentType 'audio/wav; codecs=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000' `
    -Body $audioBytes

Invoke-RestMethod: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

Same error using `-InFile audio.wav` instead of `-Body $audioBytes`.

Am I missing something? Is there an error which I don't see?

Comment: Try doing it with postman. Most likely, you are missing some data or the format is incorrect.

Comment: Can't you compare the working example request with your failing requests using a proxy like Burp or using Wireshark?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I will test it using wireshark maybe this evening.